# Winforms DataGridView Detail Edit Form

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a Winforms application written using Visual Studio 2010 in C# and SQL Server 2012 for the database.  I have a form with a DataGridView control on it.  I want to be able to double click a row and open up a new form that will have the contents of the row ready for editing.  I have researched and found one example of what I want to do here:

https://www.codeproject.com/articles/19735/datagridview-with-detail-edit-form-vs

The problem with the example I found is that the author used the drop and drag/wizard method to set up his data interactions and I am doing everything in code, so I am having a hard time understanding the example.  I am looking for a simple example in C# that shows how to open up a form with a piece of data to edit from the record that was double clicked, and then save it to the database.

Comment: Have a look at [***solution 2***](https://www.codeproject.com/questions/325428/double-click-in-datagridview-display-in-textboxes). Update the code to edit in the form all row cells instead of the single cell that was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

DataGridView in c# (the example you provided was in visual basic, not c#) there is no rowdoubleclick event. If you are deadset on using datagridview, a "workaround" would be to handle the cell double click event.

Then handler for cell doubleclick event would show a new form where the user can input all the data. then use the data to update the database and refresh the datagridview.

I'm not going to write the code out for you. but the above should give you an idea on how to implement it. try to implement it and then update your question and myself and others can help you debug.

MSDN on cell double click: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.celldoubleclick(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I cannot give a very specific answer to a very broad question. Here's my suggestion though.

You can add an event handler to the datagridview's CellMouseDoubleClick event.
In your datagridview class implementation add...

```
CellMouseDoubleClick += DataGridView_CellMouseDoubleClick;

private void DataGridView_CellMouseDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e) {
    //replace with custom form that will get passed the 
    //relevant data your datagridview uses
    Form editForm = new Form();
}
```

It gets more complicated from here which is why I can't answer your whole question specifically without spending hours on it.